# How to load image from Content folder in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm having a WebAPI project (MVC5) and just put an image in Content/Images. I'd like to load this image in C# and edit some stuff on runtime:

```
string originalFileName = "/Content/Images/Image.png";

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(originalFileName);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

This does not work unfortunatly, I'm getting an exception: System.ArgumentException - >Parameter is not valid.

My setup (code view left, solution explorer right): 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use an Application-root-relative filename (add a `~` character): `~/content/Images/Image.png`.
2. Use `Server.MapPath` to convert the Application-root-relative filename to an absolute filename.
3. Pass this absolute filename into the `Bitmap` constructor.

Like so:

```
String fileName = "~/Content/Images/Image.png";
fileName = Server.MapPath( fileName );
if( File.Exists( fileName ) ) {
    using( Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( fileName ) )
    using( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( bmp ) ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Server.MapPath does not seem to exist in the namespace? I'm only getting Microsoft.SqlServer.Server and System.Web has been added.

Comment: Ah, it's System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Thanks!